# Multiple elements on website

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, behat, mink, gherkin

i use Behat with Mink and Selenium 2.
The Problem is that i have a element twice... "Settings".
First element is (for example) `<a href="settings.php">Settings</a>` and the second thing is a quick link in non visible menu `<a href="settings.php">Settings</a>`.

**How i can select the second "Settings" element in the szenario?**

**Current example:**

```
Feature: Setting links
  Check the links

  Scenario: I check the links for settings
    Given I am logged in as "user":"name"
    Given The page is loaded
    # Now the problem... I have "Settings" twice and i would test both of them
    When I follow "Settings"
    And The page is loaded
    Then The parameter "sid" should match "[0-9]*"
    And I should see text matching "ID"
    And I should see text matching "Firstname"
    And I should see text matching "Surname"
    And I should see text matching "Street"
    And I should see text matching "Zip code"
    And I should see text matching "Country"
```

**Thank you in advance for any tips! :)**

Comment: Well I'd assume one would be visible, one wouldn't be, so check the `Displayed` property on the elements.

Comment: Hmm, how? I think you mean the FeatureContext, right?

Comment: Is your problem how to write the gherkin, how to use Selenium, or both?

Comment: I think the problem is the gherkin "command" and the selenium selector for ":second"... **Example:** `$elements = $this->findAll('a:contains("Settings")'); return count($elements) > 1 ? $elements[1] : false; // Second elemend`

Answer (score 0):

*For example.*
If you have the following html:

> `<div class="items ">`
>
> > > `<a href="settings.php">Settings</a>`
> > >
> > > `<a href="settings.php">Settings</a>`

Try to use the following step:

`And I click on ".items a:second-child" element`

Comment: `When I click on "a[href$='settings']:visible" element # Features\Context\FeatureContext::iClickOnTheElement()
      Pseudo-class "visible" not supported.`

Comment: may be try to the following steps: 

1) first step = `When I move cursor to ".items div:second-child" element`

2) second step = `And I click on the "type your xpath" element`

Comment: 1. `/**
     * @Then /^I click on xpath "(?P<selector>.*?)" element$/
     */
    public function clickXpath($selector)
    {
        $element = $this->getSession()->getPage()->find('xpath', $selector);
        $element->click();
    }



2.  /**
     * @Given /^I move cursor to "(?P<selector>.*?)" element$/
     */
    public function iMoveCursorToElement($selector)
    {
        $script = <<<JS
            $('{$selector}').addClass('hover');
JS;
        $this->getSession()->executeScript($script);
    }`

sorry for the syntax